# Allow only numbers using JavaScript for textboxes

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. I have created a form which submits details to a database. I have different textboxes, some need to accept **Only Letters** and some to allow only numbers.

I got this code while doing some research, but this code tells me of an invalid pattern.
Can you help me so that this code will allows **Only Letters**. I tried to modify the code so that it takes only letters but I failed.

```
function f_check_Lett(form){    //Only letters and numbers allowed  

    var text = form.bucketname.value;
    alert(text);

    var filter = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
    if (filter.test(text)) {
        form.submit(); 
    } else {
        form.bucketname.select();
        alert("Only Allow letters and numbers!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Get a good JavaScript book or find a good tutorial. You have to be able to solve simple tasks if you want to do anything with JavaScript, and you should be able to write this from scratch in at most ten minutes.

Comment: you have 0-9 in regular expression, it will allow numbers also.

Comment: Please tell me you are also doing validation on the server end and not just whacking the text entry straight into the database?

Answer (score 3):

use the filter as

```
var filter = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
```

---

in your filter   `[A-Za-z0-9]` will accept             any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9'

since you only need letters, remove the `0-9` from the filter.

Comment: Hi Damith, when i try to insert only letters, it highlighted the text box and says "Please match the requested format"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var filter = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test('sfjd')
```

You should definitely give [jQuery Validate Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/validate/) a try though. I've used it in many of my projects and it's very easy to implement.

Good luck!

Comment: Even if this is correct it is a poor answer. Take some time to explain it! I'll rescind my down vote once you have. And please don't just submit a quick and dirty answer then use the 5 minute grace period to shape into what it should have been, you'll simply be contributing to the FGITW problem.

Comment: @slugster How is this a poor answer?

Comment: Because you originally had one line of code and the text "Good luck!". That is a bad answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Only letters and numbers allowed
function f_check_Lett(form) {

    var text = form.bucketname.value;
    var check_format = isNaN(text);
    if (check_format == "false") {
        // your code go here 
    } else {
        // your code go here
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this allows letters only?